# Windows Update Not Working with Dual Boot

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub

I have been having dual boot *Windows 10* + *Ubuntu 20.04* for a few months, and (almost) everything has gone ok, except for one thing: Windows Update does not work anymore.

I'm stuck at version *1809*, and some apps are starting not to work anymore (such as Adobe Bridge which requires *1903*+).

Inside Windows Update, I get this error: *There were problems installing some updates, but we'll try again later*.

So I tried with restoring the image (DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth in the terminal), but I get *The source files could be found* as a response.

Then I followed every single method [this guide](https://www.wintips.org/fix-dism-source-files-could-not-be-found-windows-10-8/) (StartComponentCleanup, AnalyzeComponentStore, Install.esd, LocalSourcePath in regedit...) and no one succeeded.

After that, I tried to download the official Media Creation Tool for Windows 10 (windows installer) from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), and used it to manually update the system.

I got the following error: *We're having trouble determining if your PC can run Windows 10*, and following [this answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/were-having-trouble-determining-if-your-pc-can-run/57434ae6-89d7-41c6-9f00-4aa68f502a44) I freed up some space on my pc, but that didn't work either.

I hope that updating Windows to the last version (currently 1909) would help to solve the "Corrupted Image" problem, which would solve the issue for any future updates, but I cannot manage to do so...

Any suggestions? I [think](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-cant-install-updates-dual-boot-with/4039342f-2cdd-4cc1-b6ca-781d1c2694d1) that temporary disabling the GRUB and directly booting on Windows could somehow help, but I haven't been able to do so (Linux and Windows are on the same disk, so selecting it from BIOS always boots on the GRUB even if the partition with Windows is marked as active), and I'm always open for new ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It started working, and I don't know how.

This is even more frustrating than not working at all, after all the effort I put in fixing it, but this is what happened:

- I set the Windows partition as active to try to temporary prioritize the Windows bootloader over grub
- Despite, that, the grub was still prioritized, so I unsuccessfully tried different settings inside the BIOS
- All of a sudden a pop up appeared: it said something like *Your Windows version is not going to be supported since November 2020, click here to restart and update*
- I clicked it and... Guess what? It worked!

After the update I got the error *unknown filesystem, grub rescue* ([easily fixable](https://youtu.be/a8UuIBdMh4M)), so I think the reason why it worked is that the active partition actually changed only after a few restart (even if it seems unreasonable).

Anyway, problem solved :)

(now I'm gonna mess around or a while just to understand what happened, probably causing more problems)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.